# Breaking query results for graphical analysis Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, spyder

I have the following code in python to return the data i need from MongoDB.

```
Data = db.dataset.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$Records"
}, {
    "$unwind": "$Records.Properties"
}, {
    "$match": {
        "Records.Properties.Property.Name": 'Data'
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "value": "$Records.Properties.value"
    }
}])

timestamp = dataset.find({"Records.Properties.Property.Name":'Data'},{"timestamp":1,"_id":0})

Print Data

for a in timestamp:
   print a
```

This gives me the following results

```
  {u'ok': 1.0, u'waitedMS': 0L, u'result': [{u'value': u'-0,04149,-0,03866,-0,02914,-0,02319,-0,02027,-0,00234,0,00‌​564,0,01269,0,02852,‌​0,04648,0,05709,0,06‌​261,0,07325,0,08223,‌​0,08665,0,09229,0,09‌​688,0,09754,'}, {u'value': u'0,00218,0,00257,0,00232,0,00329,0,00279,0,00348,0,00322,0,‌​00313,0,00252,0,0031‌​1,0,00347,0,00278,0,‌​00309,0,00304,0,0038‌​2,0,00351,0,00119,0,‌​00277,0,00307'}]}

{u'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 24, 14, 59, 4)} 
{u'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 21, 5, 59, 7)}
```

I have been messing around with this for two long- and i know it should be simple. I want to break up the data so I can put the first time stamp with the first set of values, and the second time stamp with the second set of values.

Also I was trying to break up the sets of values so I can use them to build a bar graph vs time (0.01s por cada value), (each '0,xxxx' is one number).

Thank you so much for your time, really appreciate any help. Are these results lists or strings or something else? any help would be fantastic.

Comment: when i use 'y = [i.split('\t', 1)[0] for i in Data]'

it prints

'ok
waitedMS
result'

Answer (score 0):

Because the result from pymongo is in a certain format, to retrieve the data you need to use Data['result'] to extract the data.

```
for a in Data['result'][:1]:      #only print the first result in the list
    #print a['value']


    span = 2
datas = a['value'].split(",")
Data_list = [".".join(datas[i:i+span]) for i in range(0, len(datas), span)]

for a in Data_list:
    print a
```

Then to make the data usable for graphical purposed, you need to use "float" to turn the string into a value.

```
T2 = map(float, Data_list)
```

Then to graph it simply

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num = len(Data_list)
print num
x = np.arange(0,num,1)
print 'Time (s)',x

plt.plot(x, T2)
plt.show()
```